# React Native Map renders twice in componentDidMount

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I'm building a React Native application that should render a 
mapview with current location using react-native-maps.

The Mapview works but renders twice, once without a location and once with the correct location.

The location state is updated at componentWillMount and updates the state to the result of the call to Location.watchPositionAsync.

Inside the render method the Expo.Mapview location is rendered based on region that is the value of this.state.location.

**Faulty initial rendering**

[image: Faulty initial rendering]

**Correct rendering**

[image: Correct rendering]

Here is the code to my component.

```
const GEOLOCATION_OPTIONS = {
enableHighAccuracy: true,
timeout: 20000,
maximumAge: 1000
};


export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  location: { latitude: null, longitude: null, latitudeDelta: 0.0922, 
longitudeDelta: 0.0421 },
  mounted: false,
    };
}

componentWillMount() {
// checks the location when components mounts and set state to the result
Location.watchPositionAsync(GEOLOCATION_OPTIONS, this.locationChanged);
}

locationChanged = location => {

(location = {
  latitude: location.coords.latitude,
  longitude: location.coords.longitude,
  latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
  longitudeDelta: 0.0421
}),
  this.setState({ location, location });
};

static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
};


componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.mounted);
    this.state.mounted = true;
}



render() {
 return (
  <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
    <Header headerText="Company Name" />

    <View>

          {this.state.mounted ?

            (

              <Expo.MapView

                style={styles.MapView}
                showsUserLocation={true}
                region={this.state.location}
                //initialRegion={this.state.location}


                // for use with custom map
                customMapStyle={ultralight}
                provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
              >

                {biodata.map(marker => (

                  <Expo.MapView.Marker
                    key={marker.Title}
                    coordinate={{
                      longitude: parseFloat(marker.Longitude),
                      latitude: parseFloat(marker.Latitude)
                    }}
                    image={require('../assets/images/pin.png')}
                    title={marker.Title}
                    description={marker.Description}
                  >


                  <Expo.MapView.Callout onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Station', { station: marker, location: this.state.location})}>
                    <View>

                      <Text>{marker.Title}</Text>
                      <Text>{marker.Description}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </Expo.MapView.Callout>
                </Expo.MapView.Marker>
                ))}
              </Expo.MapView>

            )

            : <Spinner />

          }
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
);
}

}
```

*EDIT

I got it working adding the single line

```
this.refs.map.animateToRegion(location, 2000)
```

inside the locationChanged method. This animates to the region that is taken from the GPS location from the screen using a 2 second animation.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I didn't understood the difference between images, but a good fix would be putting the map inside a component and only rendering the map on the component after receiving the necessary props via componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: The only wrong thing that I saw is that in `componentDidMount()` you should use `this.setState({ mounted: true })` instead `this.state.mounted = true;`.

Comment: What do you mean renders once and then again?